# Rails - CanCanCan - common abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, user-roles, cancancan

I am using Rails 4, devise, Role Model and CanCanCan.

Is it possible to define an ability in ability.rb that is common to a number of roles?

For example, every logged in user can CRUD their own profile page? And then roles have specific abilities on top of that common ability?

How does that work? Do I need to create a role in Role Model for common abilities and then allow each user to have multiple roles, so that they get the common abilities as well as the role specific abilities?

For example, in my ability.rb, I have:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

      alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud


    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

      #users who are not signed in can create registration or login 

      # can read publicly available projects, programs and proposals
      can :read, Project, {:active => true, :closed => false, :sweep => { :disclosure => { :allusers => true } } }

      # {:active => true, :closed => false  &&  :Project.sweep.disclosure.allusers => true}
      # if user role is student

      if user_signed_in?
        can :crud, Profile, :user_id => user.id #[for themselves]


      elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:student)
```

So, I want students to be able to read the same things that guests can read. Is there a way to say that students can do everything that new users and users who are signed in can do (as well as the student specific abilities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a kind of composition in your roles through function calls like this

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

      #users who are not signed in can create registration or login

      # can read publicly available projects, programs and proposals

      # {:active => true, :closed => false  &&  :Project.sweep.disclosure.allusers => true}
      # if user role is student

      if user_signed_in?
        if user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:student)
          student
        else
          authenticated
        end
      else
        anonymous
      end
  end

  def anonymous
      can :read, Project, {:active => true, :closed => false, :sweep => { :disclosure => { :allusers => true } } }
  end

  def authenticated
    anonymous
    can :crud, Profile, :user_id => user.id #[for themselves]
  end

  def student
    authenticated
    #other student abilities
  end
  #other roles follow the same principal
  def teacher
    authenticated
  end
end
```

The `authenticated` function will contain the common abilities for any role and each role that needs it will just call (it's kind of inheritance where any student can do what the authenticated user can plus his abilities)

Answer (score 1):

I have here add an example ability class for your understanding. You can understand easily the code and read comments. Your code seems not good, I can point one thing, you should not manage role through `profile`, you should use `user` for assign or manage `roles`.

If you want to give same ability to a group of user then you can use this type of `||` condition `user.has_role?(:role_one) || user.has_role?(:role_two)` and pass ability block as `can :manage, [SomeClassName, SomeClassName]`.

```
    class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability

      def initialize(user)

        user ||= User.new

        #Only same user can mange his Profile
        can :manage, [Profile], :user_id => user.id

        #Give rule wise permission
        if user.admin?
          can :manage, :all
        elsif user.has_role?(:some_role_name)
          can :manage, [SomeClassName]
        elsif user.has_role?(:role_one) || user.has_role?(:role_two)
          can :manage, [SomeClassName, SomeClassName]
        else
          can :read, :all
        end

      end
    end
```

Hope this will help you complete your task.

Comment: Hi Rokibul, I'm afraid I can't understand what your example means. Do you mean that for common abilities, I need to specify all roles that can have the ability, as opposed to defining the ability and incorporating that ability into the other role that can also use that ability. I'm also afraid I don't understand why I can't have abilities in profile.rb. It's intentional as 1 user can have many profiles. I'm sorry, but I don't understand the answer you've shared.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you can not understand the code example. But one thing, I did not get you point to have multiple profile for a single user for multiple roles, you can assign multiple roles for a single user directly not through profile, it will be mess I think, anyway good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization#alternative-role-inheritance Works fine for me